# Clipping audio problem on ffmpeg live stream

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian, debian-based

in 30-40% of the live stream i get some king of distortion or clipping in the streamed audio and i have no idea why, is is only because low hardware performance maybe? I am running the stream on a Raspberry pi 3b+ CPU usage while streaming from 25 to 30% Ram usage 28% , storage device is a USB pen drive.

Here is the code:

```
ffmpeg -re -f alsa -i default -re -stream_loop -1 -i "/home/pi/Documents/Youtube/video720p.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a aac -f flv -max_muxing_queue_size 400 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/pfjd-jhjs-k3td-xxxx
```

Or i should buffer it before streaming or re-encode the audio before streaming?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does changing the encoder make a difference? Does it do it if you output to a local file?

Comment: @llogan no i did not, can you provide me with a different encoder code so i can try it? There is so many ffmpeg documentation i am not sure what to implement... I can try ac3 or flac as a example...

Comment: @llogan  I am playing mp3's if that helps to choice the right audio encoder... and do i need to recompile ffmpeg if i want to use different encoders support?

Comment: Try libmp3lame (MP3), libshine (mp3), or libfdk_aac (AAC). You'll have to re-compile if you don't have support for these. libshine may be fastest on that hardware. Alternatively you can adjust some aac settings, such as trying `-aac_coder fast` option. Does your original command sound ok on a local file? That would rule out any network related issue. You don't need `-re` for the alsa input.